Connecting to a databse in a VM
I'm practicing with conexions between java and databases for a future project but i came to a "dead" end.
My problems is that i have (System A: 192.168.1.6) and (System B: 192.168.1.254) System B is a windows 10 virtual machine hosted in VirtualBox (Net card is set as bridge)
Anyways, im trying to connect to a database hosted in System B with XAMPP but i can't make it to work in any way from System A, this is the current line im trying to connect with:
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.254:3306/caleno", "root", "");
If I try to run my program on System A it won't work, but if i change the IP for localhost and move it to System B it will run normally, for this practice it doesn't really matters where do I run it but I'd like to know how to interconnect both computers, I will also share a github link at the end where I have the current state of my project in case someone wants to try it.
I tried creating new users on xamp with global access, following the stated previously on link 1 and changing XAMP configuration as stated on link 2
I also tried the following lines of code (just for the sake of trying)
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.254:3306/caleno", "root", "");
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.254:8080/caleno", "root", ""); (this one is after doing the stuff related on link 2, with this one the program freezes and eventually later gives an error)
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.254/caleno", "root", "");(i knew this one wouldnt work but worth a shot anyways)
Link 1
Link 2
Github Repository
Additionally, inside of /com/caleno/resources there is a folder named sql, where there is a copy of my databse (tho it only has 1 table and 1 registry inside of it)
Info related to my database connection is on java/com/caleno (database file) then on FXMLDocumentController is where I use this connection in order to continue
Please, understand that I´m just a student and I´m pretty new to this world so if possible I would appreciate if you could explain what I´m doing wrong, thanks a lot in advance

My advice to sort this out would be to forget about Java until you can connect with a MySql (command line) client. Bear in mind that MySql is very choosy about where clients connect from and make sure you read the documents about specifying the connecting host when you specify grants. Once you've done all that, the Java should fall into place

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Go to your Windows VM (B) and find the MySQL installation directory, usually something like \xampp\mysql\bin\, and the filename will be my.ini. There, you need to find the bind-address parameter and change it to 0.0.0.0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

Then, your MySQL user should have the host as % or your PC's IP, not localhost.

Otherwise, execute this MySQL command on your remote MySQL server.
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

